# Cannot Complete Class Body

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have counted the curly braces and cannot figure out why the class body is incomplete. 
Everytime I try to fix the class it messes the whole class up.
The problem is the very last class in the code. The very last curly brace is the one giving me trouble with the class. I'm using Eclipse to write this in.

Here is the code for the whole program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Stocks {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Java Stocks");
    frame.setSize(700,700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints ();




    JButton button1 = new JButton("Profile");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
    panel.add(button1, c);
    button1.addActionListener(new Action());

}
static class Action implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Your Stocks");
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setSize(600,600);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Your Personal Stocks");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame2.add(panel);
        panel.add(label);

    }
        public static void main(String [] args) {   
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints ();
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Market");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
    button2.addActionListener(new Action());

        }
        static class Action2 implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Your Stocks");
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame2.setSize(600,600);
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Your Personal Stocks");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                frame2.add(panel);
                panel.add(label);

            }

        public static void main(String [] args) {
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints ();

    JButton button3 = new JButton("Users");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
    button3.addActionListener(new Action());

        }
        static class Action3 implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Your Stocks");
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame2.setSize(600,600);
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Your Personal Stocks");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                frame2.add(panel);
                panel.add(label);

            }

        public static void main(String [] args) {
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints ();
    JButton button4 = new JButton("Notes");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    c.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
    button4.addActionListener(new Action());


        }
        static class Action4 implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Your Stocks");
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame2.setSize(600,600);
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Your Personal Stocks");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                frame2.add(panel);
                panel.add(label);

            }

        public static void main(String [] args) {
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints ();
    JButton button5 = new JButton("Information");
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    c.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
    button5.addActionListener(new Action());

        }
        static class Action5 implements ActionListener {



            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Your Stocks");
                frame2.setVisible(true);
                frame2.setSize(600,600);
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Your Personal Stocks");
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                frame2.add(panel);
                panel.add(label);
            }
```

Comment: when your class code is too long for stackoverflow is time to refactor it!

Comment: You're missing 6 x `}`

Comment: There is so much static you need to ground it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to confusing indentation, it is not obvious that you are nesting your nested classes inside each other.  `Action5` is nested in `Action4`, which is nested in `Action3`, which is nested in `Action2`, which is nested in `Action`, which is nested in `Stocks`.

Either place 5 braces at the very end of the file, to close all your classes, or even better, nest them all directly in `Stocks`, not within each other.

Comment: I think it's generated by some GUI builder, and `Action1` to `Action5` are copies and aren't even used anywhere.

Comment: How would I nest them to stocks exactly? I kind of need a visual aspect. I'm not using a GUI builder, I'm using just code. it was copied and pasted so when the user clicks A button it will open a new GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use crlt+shift + f to format your code

Answer (score 0):

When you clean this up, your code should look like something like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Action implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Your Stocks");
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setSize(600,600);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Your Personal Stocks");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame2.add(panel);
        panel.add(label);
    }
}

public class Stocks {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Java Stocks");
        frame.setSize(700,700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints ();

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Profile");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
        panel.add(button1, c);
        button1.addActionListener(new Action());
    }

}
```

My advice #1: first learn to code with keyboard, not mouse.

My advice #2: if you aren't sure what `static` modifier is for and what are the implications, don't use it.